# How do I make a RemoveFromCart function?

Tags: php, html, paypal

I've been struggling with a problem that doesn't allow me to delete my items from Cart. Whenever I try to do that, the error occurs with name "POST parameter id is required".

On the contary, it surprisingly works with adding items to the cart. This is the script I use for showing items in the cart, and deleting:

```
<div class="container">
            <?php
                foreach(Cart::GetRooms() as $room) {
                    ?> 
                    <div>
                        <div class="media">
                            <img class="align-self-start mr-3" src="<?=$room->GetData()["icon_url"]?>" alt="Room icon" width="200px">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h5 class="mb-0"><?=$room->GetData()["title"]?></h5>

                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <p>Cena: <span class="text-success font-weight-bold"><?=$room->GetData()["price"]?> <?=SHOP_CURRENCY?></span></p>

                                    <form method="post" action="/api/cart/removeItem.php">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="room_id" value="<?=$room->GetData()["id"]?>" />
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">X</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            ?>
```

This is the script that is supposed to remove items from the cart

```
<?php
require_once "../../settings.php";

$id = POST("id", true);

Cart::RemoveFromCart((int) $id);

http_response_code(302);
header("Location: /cart.php");
```

```
 public static function RemoveFromCart(int $id) : bool {
        $db = MysqliDb::getInstance();
        $db->where("id", $id);
        $db->delete("cart");
        return true;
    }
```

and this is the POST function i wrote myself in case it was needed

```
function POST(string $key, bool $required=false, bool $secure=true) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$key])) {
        if($required) {
            exit("POST parameter $key is required");
        } 
        else {

        }
    }

    $return_val = $_POST[$key];

    if($secure) {
        $return_val = htmlentities($return_val);
    }

    return $return_val;
}
```

Comment: @Berto99 yes, it does execute. I can see "hit"

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if that was the problem

Comment: have you ensured that the id you're expecting to delete is acutally sent in a post body
?

Comment: yes, checked it a few times and it is the one. I use similar method for adding products to the cart, and it works, but removing doesn't

Answer (score 0):

in your form you have

```
<input type="hidden" name="room_id" value="<?=$room->GetData()["id"]?>" />
```

but in your script you are looking for a `id` property inside the request, so you should change it either to this

```
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$room->GetData()["id"]?>" />
```

or to this:

```
$id = POST("room_id", true);
```

Comment: I see no errors, but the item is still not removed from the cart

Comment: if you are using this package https://github.com/JonathanFrias/PHP-Database-Helper the "delete" method does not accept parameters

Comment: @yuvi probably $room->GetData()["id"] is not printing out the correct id

Comment: I'm using this one https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class from 8th feb 2018

Comment: I just checked, and it seems fine, the room's id is 3 in my database

Comment: @yuvi the delete method has a bool as return type, what is returning?

Comment: if i remove "RemoveFromCard" method, and vardump($id) in removeItem.php it returns string(1) "1"

Comment: @yuvi no, what i would like to know is what is returning "$db->delete("cart");"

Comment: oh, it returns "bool(true)"

Comment: also when i click the button, the query is not deleted

Comment: "the query is not deleted " what you mean? is not been runned?